# Not reading specific file

Tags: java

I have this file name Invictus.txt with content

```
Invictus
William Ernest Henley (1849–1903).

Out of the night that covers me,
Black as the pit from pole to pole,
I thank whatever gods may be
For my unconquerable soul.

In the fell clutch of circumstance
I have not winced nor cried aloud.
Under the bludgeonings of chance
My head is bloody, but unbowed.

Beyond this place of wrath and tears
Looms but the Horror of the shade,
And yet the menace of the years
Finds and shall find me unafraid.

It matters not how strait the gate,
How charged with punishments the scroll,
I am the master of my fate:
I am the captain of my soul
```

and I am using

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
```

but

```
input.hasNext
```

is returning null, 
its working fine with other files!!!

Comment: are you referencing the full (absolute) or relative file path?

Comment: @Mureinik, If file is not found, than `FielNotFoundException` will be thrown. Returning null is another issue.

Comment: file is being found exception is not thrown, but it doesnt read the content !!

Comment: @user2864175, there was other issue,  post your code.

Answer (score 0):

`input.hasnext`  is wrong, Use `input.hasNext`.

> **public boolean hasNext()**
>
> Returns true if this scanner has another
>   token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to
>   scan. The scanner does not advance past any input.

Your file is probably `empty`. Thats why you are getting `null`.

Comment: You are technically correct, the method is called `hasNext` with a capital "N", however invoking `input.hasnext` with the lowercase letter would not return null, it would cause a compilation error, and the program would never run.

Comment: @Masud, but the OP has posted the content inside the file

Comment: @lazyprogrammer, That content, he may paste to file, but forgot to save.

Comment: @Masud then it has to be one hell of a blunder!!